# Show a container view above uinavigation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know how to show a containerview controller in front the navigation view? And then also remove it based on a notification?

Below is how I get it to show in my current view, but I want it to cover the entire screen, including the navigation view.  I am thinking I can create a custom uinavigation controller that uses the below code?

```
-(void)showRate {

if(nil == self.rateView) {

    self.rateView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Rate"];
}

// Show the container view

self.rateView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -600, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.rateView.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.rateView.view];

[self addChildViewController:self.rateView];
[self.rateView didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut) animations:^{
    //Slide the waitview on screen
    self.rateView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //do nothing at end
}];
}
```

Comment: Create a view and set `self.view = viewName` then remove it by animating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add any subview to the utmost top, even over the navigation bar, use this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourSubView];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: To remove the subview, use [yourSubView removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

Add your view on main window if you want to cover the whole screen including navigation bar and status bar, if you want to cover only view then you can add your custom view as subview.